# Qt 4.8.1 for Visual Studio strange error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I managed to install Qt for Visual Studio (2010) easily but when I compile a simple app I get a strange error regarding **Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets** :

```
Error 1 error : Required file "" is missing.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets   147 6
```

line 147 being:

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to pinpoint the problem.
I copied **mspdb100.dll** in my VisualStudio\VC\bin folder for some reason.
Deleting it fixed all errors